# Split lists issue

Tags: list, prolog

I have a problem in Prolog, I have a list with 81 items and I need to get just 9 items from it in different positions each time, for example if my list is:

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
 split(L1,2,L) the result will be L1=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18].
```

My procedure is

```
split([X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8], 0, [X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8], []).
split([X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8|Y], 1, [X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8], Y).
split([X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8|Y], N, [X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8|T], Z) :-
   N > 0,
   N1 is N-1,
   split(Y, N1, T, Z).
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? You get an error? The result is not as expected?

Comment: What does the '2' represent in your example `split(L1, 2, L)`? By "different positions each time" do you mean you want it to backtrack and exhaust all possible options, or do you plan to pass a different parameter to request a different sublist? If backtrack, are sublists allowed to overlap?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the ability of `length/2` to create lists, and `append/3` to split lists. Basically:

`extract(List, N, Len, E)` is true when *E* is a list of length *Len* from position *N* (0-based indexing) in *List*

```
extract(List, N, Len, E) :-
    length(E, Len),
    length(Before, N),
    append(Before, Rest, List),
    append(E, _, Rest).
```

There are many other ways to do it of course, but this is conceptually easy (at least for me).

To your **exact** question, you could write:

```
extract_list(List, Len, Nth, E) :-
    length(E, Len),
    LenBefore is Len*(Nth-1),
    length(Before, LenBefore),
    append(Before, Rest, List),
    append(E, _, Rest).
```

I have switched the position of the arguments as the convention is input arguments first, output last.

Answer (score 1):

the minimal edit fix for your code is

```
split([X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8], 1, [X,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8|_]).
split(Y, N, [_X,_X1,_X2,_X3,_X4,_X5,_X6,_X7,_X8|Z]):-
   N>1, N1 is N-1, split(Y, N1, Z).
```

This won't work if the length of the original list is smaller than `9*N`, for a call `split(Y,N,....)`.

Comment: I'm not sure it works at all. The first rule should have a tail in the input list anyway, and then it works for any length (bigger than 9) `split(.... X8|_]).`